# Create Javascript Array with known size / performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I refactored this code already, but it still feels like this could be written better (without external libs). Any suggestions?

```
  // Old
  const filters = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 54; i += 1) {
    const currentDateDisplay = getStartDate(i, new Date().getFullYear());
    filters.push({ text: currentDateDisplay, value: currentDateDisplay });
  }

  // New
  const filters2 = [...Array(53).keys()].map((item) => ({
    text: getStartDate(item, new Date().getFullYear()),
    value: getStartDate(item, new Date().getFullYear()),
  }));
```

Edit: Looks like sometimes it's better to use the old for loop, especially when it comes to performance. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: the first one is more elementary and `better`

Comment: Save the `getStartDate(item, new Date().getFullYear())` in a variable instead of repeating it twice

Comment: Where is your external lib? Your code example is incomplete.

Comment: Why does the first example use `getDateDisplay` and the second does not? What exactly is returned by `getStartDate`? If it is an object, should it be a shared reference to the same object for both the `text` and `value` properties?

Comment: good catch, forgot that function, i removed it in the examples, it is not needed. @str

Comment: You shouldn't be worrying about performance if you're only creating dealing with 53 objects inside of an array. Pick whatever is easier for you to understand and **then** worry about performance if it becomes a bottleneck in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that the 1st implementation you wrote seems more intuitive, however, the 2nd method could be written differently.

By first calling `new Array(53)`, you create an array of 53 elements. By then calling `.map((_, index) => {})`, you have access to the index variable (using `_` for the `item`, as it's `undefined` anyway). You don't have to clone the new array by spreading it, so simply using this code would work for you:

```js
const filters = new Array(53).map((_, index) => ({
  text: getStartDate(index, new Date().getFullYear()),
  value: getStartDate(index, new Date().getFullYear())
}));
```

Comment: And for the `.map()` as well, fixed it

Comment: `Array#map` does not work like that on sparse arrays.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of this

Answer (score 0):

You want to initiate an array with an initial values? thats the use-case for [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const filters2 = new Array(53).fill({
  text: getStartDate(0, new Date().getFullYear()),
  value: getStartDate(0, new Date().getFullYear())
});
```

Comment: This would not work, as the `Array.prototype.fill` method is used to fill every element of the array with the same value. Judging by the use of `item` (which is actually the index in his case) in the `getStartDate` function, each element should have different values.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer your `old` variant as it is more readable for me. In my view, code should be more readablem not shorter.

In addition, according to the test the `old` [variant is faster](https://jsbench.me/iuk99pllb6/1):

```
const filters = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 54; i += 1) {
    const currentDateDisplay = getStartDate(i, new Date().getFullYear());
    filters.push({ text: currentDateDisplay, value: currentDateDisplay });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the old school methods are not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Which style you prefer is ultimately a matter of taste.
If you prefer the second—more functional-like—style you can simplify it as below:

```
const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const filters2 = Array.from(new Array(53), (_, i) => {
  const startDate = getStartDate(i, year);
  return {text: startDate, value: startDate};
});
```

It replaces `[...Array(53).keys()].map()` with the more suitable `Array.from` and does not evaluate the same values multiple times.
The performance differences in such a simple case are negligible and you should use the code that is more readable to you and your team.